# unexpected token `<` when trying to do POST in php

Tags: php

I have a php file like this

```
<?php

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo $_POST['name'];
?>
```

then I do a post request using postman,

[image]

The actual error is `Undefined index: name`

Comment: show the code inside the methods add

Comment: We need more code. What is before that you show?

Comment: Switch the result view away from JSON, might be the tool’s error message and the actual result from the server is different. In any case echoing name won’t result in valid JSON.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen great, saw the error, it's `Undefined index: name`

Comment: @halojoy that's all the code I have.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try like this:
Select 'form-data' radio button under body near the 'x-www-form-urlencode' and try again.

Answer (score -1):

You have set the Content-type to json, so you should return json response.
change  the statement from
 $_POST['name'] to json_encode($_POST['name']);